# Basic Bayesian reasoning question -- what is wrong with this "equational" argument?

Tags: bayesian

Let's say that we have a model:

$y + x = \epsilon$, $\epsilon \sim N(0, 1)$.

After observing a value for $y$, we can write $x$ as:

$x = \epsilon - y$

Since $y$ is just a constant, and $\epsilon$ is standard normally distributed, it seems that we can claim:

$\epsilon - y \sim N(-y, 1)$

and thus:

$p(x \mid y) = N(x; -y, 1)$ where $N$ is the normal pdf.

But this makes no sense as there is no mention of a prior for $x$ anywhere. So what went wrong with this "equational" reasoning argument?

Comment: Note: You haven't said anything about whether the random variables **X** and **Y** are *i.i.d* or not...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to interpret your statement $\epsilon \sim \mathcal N(0, 1)$. If $\epsilon \sim \mathcal N(0, 1)$ is taken to mean that $\epsilon$ is *marginally* $\mathcal N(0, 1)$ then your logic falls apart at concluding that $[\epsilon - y \mid Y = y] \sim \mathcal N(-y, 1)$. This is because there is no reason whatsover to conclude that $[\epsilon \mid Y = y] \sim \mathcal N(0, 1)$; the assumption is made about the marginal distribution of $\epsilon$, but if $\epsilon$ and $Y$ are dependent we cannot make such a strong conclusion about the  *conditional* distribution of $[\epsilon \mid Y]$.

Now, on the other hand, if one interprets $\epsilon \sim \mathcal N(0, 1)$ to mean that $[\epsilon \mid Y = y] \sim \mathcal N(0, 1)$ then your logic works. This is a standard assumption in parametric linear regression, after relabeling the variables slightly; one assumes $Y = X\beta + \epsilon$ and assumes that $[\epsilon \mid X] \sim \mathcal N(0, \sigma)$, from which is follows that $[Y \mid X] \sim \mathcal N(X\beta, \sigma)$.

Answer (score 0):

"Since y is just a constant..."..it is not a constant. It is a sample from a distribution. The errors follow!!

Comment: If you're computing the conditional distribution of $x$ given the data, $f(x|y)$, as would often be done in a Bayesian context, $y$ is constant.

Comment: The equation mentioned is for x and not x|y. There is no mention of a marginal distribution

Comment: There's a mention of $p(x \mid y) $ right there in the question.

Comment: You're right...my bad!! serves me right for looking up problems during the hangries!!

Comment: I guess my main problem was with putting up $x=\epsilon - y$ followed by "since y is just a constant..." I read that and didn't proceed further

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem in your reasoning, except you want a prior on $x$.
Note that $p(x,y,\epsilon) = p(x|y,\epsilon)p(y)p(\epsilon)$.

Comment: Hmmm, so what would be the correct equation for $p(x \mid y)$ that has a $p(x)$ or $p(y)$ term in it? $p(x, y, \epsilon) = 1$ iff $x + y = \epsilon$, right? I'm not seeing how it's helpful?